# how to upgrade python3.5 to python3.6 in Virtual Machine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, virtual-machine

I have a virtual machine (Azure):

```
vm:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

It is installed with `Python 3.5.6`, and I would like to upgrade it to `3.6` to be compatible with some libraries. I have tried the following:

```
vm:~$ python --version
Python 3.5.6 :: Anaconda, Inc.
vm:~$ sudo apt-get install python3.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.6
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.6'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.6'
vm:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade python3.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.6
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.6'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.6'
```

May I know how to go about doing it?

Can I do it from `JupyterLab` also?

Comment: Depends on your distribution.  I'm running 20.04, and only python3.8 and python3.9 are available.  `apt search python | grep ^python3\\\.`

Comment: Since you're using Jupyter, I assume you're doing some data science-related work. From this, I also assume you're using conda. You can try `conda install python=3.6`; do this in a new env to avoid breaking your current env

Comment: hi @HongOoi, it's a virtual machine, so there's no conda installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a suggestion:

Follow this https://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get/865569#865569

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

If there are problems with update, check this [https://www.xmodulo.com/how-to-fix-apt-get-update-error-on-ubuntu.html#:~:text=This%20error%20can%20happen%20when,%22%20apt%2Dget%20update%20%22](https://www.xmodulo.com/how-to-fix-apt-get-update-error-on-ubuntu.html#:%7E:text=This%20error%20can%20happen%20when,%22%20apt%2Dget%20update%20%22).

```
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade python3.6
```

After that, do the following in JupyterLab (OS: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial)

**Upgrade pip:**

```
!pip install --upgrade pip
```

**Install virtual environment:**

```
!pip install virtualenv
```

**Create new kernel with Python3.6:**

```
!virtualenv -p python3.6 Python_3_6
```

**Create a new kernel option:**

```
!python -m ipykernel install --user --name=Python_3_6
```

This would create a new kernel option with the name `Python_3_6` in the menu when starting a new notebook. Now this new kernel would be compatible to run those libraries you need!